# Error: Method __toString() must not throw an exception, caught Error: Call to a member function getCode() on null

Tags: php

I'm new to php, and I see this error quite often, but I'm always unsure about how to solve this problem, can somebody please help me how to fix this in this method?

This is my __toString() method:

```
/**
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString(): string
{
    return (string)$this->name .' - '. $this->surname .' - '. $this->getSubject()->getCode();
}
```

Thank you

Comment: Result of `$this->getSubject()` is `NULL` Why? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is caused because something inside `__toString()` method caused an exception.

As the error says method `getSubject()` returned `null` value and then calling `null->getCode()` throws exception. Better solution is:

```
public function __toString(): string
{
    $subj = $this->getSubject();
    $code = is_null($subj) ? "" : $subj->getCode(); /* instead of empty string can be any value you want when subject is missing */

    return (string)$this->name .' - '. $this->surname .' - '. $code;
}
```